# My laptop, and only my laptop, keeps disconnecting from wifi signal booster

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop

I have a signal booster (or router, I don't really know the difference) and my android, other laptops connect and keep connected to this signal booster without a problem. The thing is, with my new laptop I get periodically  disconnected from the internet, but still connected to the wifi network. While all the other laptops and devices don't have this problem whatsoever. It's worth to mention that my laptop's wifi works flawlessly with other wifi netoworks, it's only with this one that I have this problem. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that my laptop is new and this signal booster is old?

Thanks

Comment: Your older devices are probably 2.4 GHz and your new laptop is likely 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz.  Maybe try ensuring you are only using the 2.4 GHz band for starters.  Update the laptop BIOS, and Wi-Fi driver as well.

Comment: If you're still, connected to WiFi, it may be DNS resolution causing the issue, assuming it occurs on opeing a new site. Check if DNS resolution is set the same as on other PC's.

Comment: @John Thanks for the reply. I already checked that and I regularly update my drivers

Comment: Does my answer above satisfy you?